# Logout sinch user in iOS

Tags: swift, sinch

I'm working on call/video application. I'm using SINCH SDK and i successfully integrated in swift project and call video work fine but i have a problem that when user is logged out from application still received a notification, i don't know why i used this function to logout

```
func logOutSinchUser() {
    if let client = self._client {
        client.stopListeningOnActiveConnection()
        client.terminate()
        client.unregisterPushNotificationData()
    }

    self._client = nil
}
```

Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: Based on what mentioned [here](https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/ios/), the `unregisterPushNotificationData` should achieve it: "The push notification data can be unregistered by calling the `unregisterPushNotificationData` method. This disables incoming calls using push notifications addressed to the specific device." You might want to check you are re-register it after calling `logOutSinchUser` (it might be by mistake)...

Comment: Hi @Ghassan did you manage to find a swift solution to log out Sinch user? Thanks

Comment: Logout in sinch not work ! the app still receive call even if you are logout in sinch ! i found a solution not a best but its work on me In didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload you need to get the remoteId from header and in handleRemoteNotification check if the localUser is the same of remoteId you need you show the notification of call and if not you will ignore this notification!

Comment: @Ghassan I am trying your method but I am failing to see the logic behind it. So if the remote userID matches the local userID, that means someone is calling using the same ID. The problem I have is that the Sinch server still thinks that the device is still registered with the old token after I logged out the user so the call to old user will still be received by the device that has a new user.

Comment: for that i do this method because logout not work on sinch ! so in didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload you put this code to get the remote_id from header  if let aHeaders = result?.call().headers {
                    callerIdz = aHeaders["to"] as? String
                    self.handleRemoteNotification(userInfo: payload as NSDictionary)} and in handleRemoteNotification you check if the remote id you get it is the same of user he logged in if there you handle call like that code if _client.userId != callerIdz {  print("Not match") return} else { you handle call}

Comment: @Ghassan  my app is not working in background can you help

Answer (score 0):

Please try to unregister the push token first(unregisterPushNotificationDeviceToken if you use sinch managed push) before you terminate the sinch client.

Also use terminateGracefully instead, to give the SDK more time to handle the unregistration process before shut off.

Could be sth like:

```
func logOutSinchUser() {
    if let client = self._client {
        client.stopListeningOnActiveConnection()
        client.unregisterPushNotificationDeviceToken()
        client.terminateGracefully()
    }
    self._client = nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bo Li! A quick question: how do you implement this code? Thanks!

Comment: i need your help in sinch